# Not able to connect to webservice from a WP7 emulator

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     WebClient wb = new WebClient();
     wb.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wb_DownloadStringCompleted);
     wb.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265"));

     }
    void wb_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xmlResult = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

    }
```

This is code i have used. I am getting an error "Unable to connect to the remote server".
I am able to connect to internet from the IE browser in the emulator.

Suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: What binding, and the port, run the service on?
 WCF?

Comment: the service am trying to connect is a free yahoo api for weather.

Comment: NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();
            cred.Domain = "XXXXX";
            cred.UserName = "YYYYY";
            cred.Password = "ZZZZZZ";
            wb.Credentials = cred;
            WebProxy wp = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
            wp.Credentials = cred;
            wb.Proxy = wp;


if the following code is addded (of webproxy) connection established in case of a web app. Can anyone suggest i how to use webproxy on mobile app(wp7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to restart your emulator ? Because it happens to me : I got this error with the emulator but none with a simple console programm. After a restart of VS, it works.

Comment: Restarting the emulator or VS is not helping me.

Comment: Ah...I wasted 4 hours. WebClient on Emulator somewhat not worked/connected to the outside of the computer. I made a WinForm application and it worked fine. I restart the Emulator and it worked! darn!!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you have provided. Are you sure you're not stuck behind a firewall or something that blocks your request? Try using Fiddler (or a product like it) to see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

To allow  the Emulator in friewall.

- Open Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs
- Click on "Change Settings" to enable "Allow another program"
- Browse - > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\1.0\XDE.exe"
- Tick Public / Private Network or both as you are connected to internet.