# Windows Phone 8 Emulator not connecting to internet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, emulation

I am trying to connect Windows Phone 8 emulator to the internet. I have tried all the tricks and steps given in Stack overflow or any other site but I am unable to get it.

I tried this:

Step 1 - using Hyper-V start the server, once started u can see the two new network adapters added in the (network sharing) page.

Step 2 - go to your visual studio IDE where your application runs, using Emulator run your application, once started try to open IE, it will not connect to internet.

Step 3 - now again come back to network sharing page right click on external adapter which was created newly select properties, hit on sharing tab, now check the two options to have tick mark if not tick that two options and click on OK.

Step 4 - internal adapter which was created newly will be changing the domain name from Unidentified network to your shared Domain name, once changed try to access the IE again in emulator which runs already. now i hope the internet connection works.

But once it's done it is showing:

The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to connect to the Windows Phone operating system:

The phone didn't respond to the connect request.

Some functionality may be disabled.

The resolution to which I found on internet was:

All you have to do is going to "Network and Internet --> Network Connections", right click on "vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port) Windows Phone Emulator" and Enable it.

But it was already enabled .
So I don't know how to make internet work.

Answer (score 1):

Some connection tools *on the host* can have negative effects when used with the emulator; I found having cisco VPN client installed on the host prevented the emulator from finding the internet. Other VPN clients may have similar side-effects. I simply uninstalled cisco (the inbuilt windows VPN is fine for what I need) and it worked perfectly.

I've also seen problems where it won't find the internet after the host has been suspended / resumed. In *that* scenario, it turned out to be bad network drivers. I installed a dedicated Intel NIC (rather than the on-board NIC on the motherboard) - problem solved.

Basically, Hyper-V is a bit fussy.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check whether you are using latest internet explorer 10 or not. if not update and check it.

2.Still if it's not working, it could be the problem with your display drivers. You should have WDDM 2.0 drivers. Graphic card also goes well.

Comment: But in the emulator how can I check whether it is IE10 or  not

Comment: you shouldn't check in the emulator, u should check in your system. what about your display drivers?

Comment: fine with your ie10. but you should hav at least WDDM 2.0 display drivers. If your display drivers are of old version then you need to place graphic card or update your drivers.

Comment: how to check for the display drivers

Comment: check this link                                          http://driver-pro.com/static/images/article-content/ati-driver-site/ati-correct-device-manager.jpg

Comment: i checked it is WDDM 1.1 . is there any other way to make it work cause I can't change the drivers or update them.

Comment: sorry, i don't think there's other option. purchase a graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any proxy servers which require credentials for connecting to the internet, it may not probably get connected from the emulator.

This is because it doesnt support proxy authentication. The class for authentication are missing in the phone version of .Net

Please see the below post .

[Not able to connect to webservice from a WP7 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562887/not-able-to-connect-to-webservice-from-a-wp7-emulator)